# Keep RTC time in a loop

Tags: arduino-mega, rtc, hc-sr04

I recently started a project with HC-SR04 sensors and RTC DS1302 clock. The idea is when a sensor detects an object, call and keep a timestamp (hh:mm:ss) all over the loop until Else If{} appears,  but I don't know how to.

```
#include <DS1302.h>
#include <Time.h>
#include <TimeLib.h>
#define echoPin 12 // Echo Pin
#define trigPin 13 // Trigger Pin

time_t t = now();
DS1302 rtc(6,20,21);
String inTime;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
}

void loop(){
    long duration, distance;
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);  
    delayMicroseconds(2); 
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10); 
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
    distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;

   if (distance <= 4) { 
    inTime= rtc.getTimeStr();
    Serial.println(inTime);

    } 

    else if (distance >= 5 || distance <= 0){
    Serial.println("Out of range");

    }

  delay(500);
}
```

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check '{' and '}' pairs in your code.

```
void loop(){
    long duration, distance;
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);  
    delayMicroseconds(2); 
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10); 
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
    distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;
    if (distance <= 4) { 
        inTime= rtc.getTimeStr();
        Serial.println(inTime);

   } 
} //<--- what is this little fella doing here?
    else if (distance >= 5 || distance <= 0){
    Serial.println("Out of range");
    }

delay(500);
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's because my original code is too long and is normal miss or add some {}

Comment: Well, the machine will not accept your excuses. You must be precise here. Maybe you can try to split code into few files?  
Also, look at your 'distance' variable. Its type is 'long'. After line   
        'distance = (duration/2) / 29.1; '  you are loosing what is after comma.